# Svg on my website (map svg) I want to be able to zoom in and out of the map

Tags: javascript, html

I'm Making a Strategy Game There is only one map right now I will add more maps soon But I can't zoom the map right now It would be great if someone from the community can help.
Svg on my website (map svg) I want to be able to zoom in and out of the map
Js code:

```
function svgturkiyeharitasi() {
  const element = document.querySelector('#svg-turkiye-haritasi');
  const info = document.querySelector('.il-isimleri');

  element.addEventListener(
    'mouseover',
    function (event) {
      if (event.target.tagName === 'path' && event.target.parentNode.id !== 'guney-kibris') {
        info.innerHTML = [
          '<div>',
          event.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-iladi'),
          '</div>'
        ].join('');
      }
    }
  );

  element.addEventListener(
    'mousemove',
    function (event) {
      info.style.top = event.pageY + 25 + 'px';
      info.style.left = event.pageX + 'px';
    }
  );

  element.addEventListener(
    'mouseout',
    function (event) {
      info.innerHTML = '';
    }
  );

  element.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function (event) {
      if (event.target.tagName === 'path') {
        const parent = event.target.parentNode;
        const id = parent.getAttribute('id');
        if (id === 'guney-kibris') {
          return;
        }

        window.location.href = ('#' + id + '-' + parent.getAttribute('data-plakakodu')
        );
      }
    }
  );
}
```

Site:http://188.132.197.244/harita

```
function svgturkiyeharitasi() {
  const element = document.querySelector('#svg-turkiye-haritasi');
  const info = document.querySelector('.il-isimleri');

  let isDragging = false;

  let startCoords = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  let currentCoords = { x: 0, y: 0 };

  let scale = 1;

  element.addEventListener(
    'mouseover',
    function (event) {
      if (event.target.tagName === 'path' && event.target.parentNode.id !== 'guney-kibris') {
        info.innerHTML = [
          '<div>',
          event.target.parentNode.getAttribute('data-iladi'),
          '</div>'
        ].join('');
      }
    }
  );

  element.addEventListener(
    'mousemove',
    function (event) {
      if (isDragging) {
        const deltaX = event.clientX - currentCoords.x;
        const deltaY = event.clientY - currentCoords.y;

        element.style.transform = `translate(${deltaX}px, ${deltaY}px) scale(${scale})`;

        currentCoords = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
      } else {
        info.style.top = event.pageY + 25 + 'px';
        info.style.left = event.pageX + 'px';
      }
    }
  );

  element.addEventListener(
    'mouseout',
    function (event) {
      info.innerHTML = '';
    }
  );

  element.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function (event) {
      if (event.target.tagName === 'path') {
        const parent = event.target.parentNode;

        const id = parent.getAttribute('id');

        if (id === 'guney-kibris') {
          return;
        }

        window.location.href = ('#' + id + '-' + parent.getAttribute('data-plakakodu'));
      }
    }
  );

  // Fare tekerleği ile yakınlaştırma ve uzaklaştırma

  element.addEventListener('wheel', function (event) {
    if (event.deltaY > 0) {
      // Tekerlek aşağı kaydırıldığında uzaklaştır
      scale -= 0.1; // Ölçeği azaltabilirsiniz
    } else {
      // Tekerlek yukarı kaydırıldığında yakınlaştır
      scale += 0.1; // Ölçeği artırabilirsiniz
    }

    element.style.transform = `scale(${scale})`;
  });

  // Haritayı sürüklemek için olay dinleyicileri
  element.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    isDragging = true;
    startCoords = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
    currentCoords = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
  });

  window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    isDragging = false;
  });

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (event) {
    if (isDragging) {
      const deltaX = event.clientX - startCoords.x;
      const deltaY = event.clientY - startCoords.y;

      element.style.transform = `translate(${deltaX}px, ${deltaY}px) scale(${scale})`;

      currentCoords = { x: event.clientX, y: event.clientY };
    }
  });
}
```

This code for the site I want to zoom this code in Svg for Site as I will add UI soon so I want it to be in a way that does not cover UI.
Site:http://188.132.197.244/harita